# Utilizar Banco de Dados em Produção PostGres - Nâo Aceita Utilizar Tabela com CamelCase

Tags: java

Bom dia a todos.

Estou tentando comunicar com um banco de dados Postgress e até aqui tudo bem. Dentro do banco tenho uma tabela chamada ClienteLegado. Mas toda vez que a aplicação sobe é criado uma tabela cliente_legado.

Já tentei utilizar com @Table(name="ClienteLegado"). Ja tentei sem o @Table e utilizar o nome da classe igualzinho a tabela, mas o Hibernate insiste em 
criar esta tabela cliente_legado. Como vou apenas consumir os dados desta tabela e não posso correr o risco de fazer alteração no banco, estou comentando a linha abaixo:

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Como estou desenvolvendo uma Api Rest, o retorno que eu tenho é da tabela cliente_legado e não da tabela ClienteLegado.

Isso poderia ser algum problema no application.properties ?

Configuração do application.properties

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/comunicacao
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=056409

#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-   strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
#server.port=8083
```

Configuração da Classe

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ClienteLegado")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
// @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "ClienteLegadoId")
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, solução encontrada foi.

Nas configurações do application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit- strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Mapeamento nome da tabela

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="\"ClienteLegado\"")
```

Mapeando nome dos campos

```
 @Column(name="\"Codigo\"")
 private String codigo;

 @Column(name="\"Nome\"")
 private String nome;
 Gets e Sets
```

Vale lembrar que este caso é um caso que foge da regra, pois a tabela no banco de dados do cliente contempla o nome em camel case , tal como ClienteLegado.
Fazendo testes quando o nome da tabela é em minúsculo que é o padrão do 
PostGres, não existe a necessidade disso tudo bastando seguir pelo método tradicional.
Para entender como eram montadas as classes foi necessário fazer um engenharia reversa com o Eclipse onde montei as entidades apartir do banco de dados. O Eclipse montou isso e segui o exemplo e deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

Spring JPA por padrão usa underscore para dividir nomes em camel case. Altere o naming strategy no `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088398/5360385)

Comment: Alterando o naming strategy agora ele continua criando a tabela assim : cliente_legado onde o nome da tabela no banco é ClienteLegado.  No meu ponto de vista ele não deveria criar tabela alguma. Tem mais alguma ideia do que possa ser este problema ?

Comment: Qual versão do Spring você ta usando?

Comment: O PostgreSQL utiliza dois tipos de identificadores, o identificador comum que não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas e o identificador delimitado (ou quoted identifier), escrito entre aspas e que tem que obrigatoriamente seguir exatamente como foi escrito em sua definição. Assim nome, NOME e Nome se referem ao mesmo identificador mas "identificador", "Identificador" ou "IDENTIFICADOR" são diferentes. Verifique como você, ou seu aplicativo, fez a definição em seu banco de dados.